# conformal map of a portion of unit disk onto upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

How do we construct a conformal map from $\{z=x+iy,x>1/2,|x+iy|<1\}$ onto the upper half plane? My idea is  first create a sector sending one of the two intersection points to infinity.Any help would be appreciated.